# Can I programmatically instantiate a named LocalDb instance?

Tags: connection-string, dbcontext, localdb

I have a WinForms application that is using LocalDb.  Of course on my development box, this works fine.  When I deploy the application to another box, I am getting the following error message:

"A network-related or instance specific error ocurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server."

I have gone through many of the posts on Stackoverflow on this issue - most seem related to the connection string.

One of the issues I am having is that on my development box, I started a named LocalDb instance. On my install target, I am running the LocalDb installation MSI.

For the installed instance, is there a way to programmatically instantiate a named LocalDb instance or a way to connect to the default LocalDb instance?

Is it possible to programmatically instantiate a named LocalDb instance?

Or can I create a connection string that can be used to open my LocalDb database using (localdb)\v11.0;

I am also using DbContext in the development - again on the development box, LocalDb and DbContext work fine.  Does the use of DbContext and EF affect the LocalDb connection string on the target box?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways actually:

1. [LocalDBCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh214784.aspx) function from LocalDB API, for native C/C++ code and through PInvoke
2. [system.data.localdb / localdbinstances element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh309441.aspx) in your application's app.config (.NET applications only, requires .NET 4.0.2 or later)

Comment: Krztsztof - thanks very much! - it also looks as through I need to include .Net 4.5 in the install to support this..

Comment: Correct, if you want to go with the app.config you need .NET 4.0.2 or later

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof - Would you be able to point me to an example app.config for LocalDb?  It looks like I have cleared this problem but am encountering an error "invalid key value for AttachDbFilename"